# Multi dropdowns first one selected remove the value from 2nd dropdown up to 7 dropdowns

Tags: javascript

i have 7 dropdown boxes in html. They will all get populated the same data. What I am trying to do is when the first dropdown is selected it would remove the selected item from the next dropdown. So, if you Have data: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I in one dropdown if I select B in the first drop down then in the next dropdown it should only show A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I and so on up to 7 dropdowns. I dont know what would be the best way to approach this in JavaScript.  Sample Code: Below code doesn't work on IE7 & IE8 on my pc, Any one know what changes i have to make it to work this code..  **Thanks for your help in advance**

```
 function callSave(select) {

        var parent = select.parentNode;    

       var usedValues = {};    

      for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; ++i) {

        var s = parent.children[i];

      if (s.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
           continue;
        }        

     if (s.value != '') {
         usedValues[ s.value ] = s;
      } 
  }    

   for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; ++i) {      
      var s = parent.children[i];        
      if (s.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
          continue;
      }        

      for (var j = 0; j < s.children.length; ++j) {           
         var o = s.children[j];             
        if (o.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'option') {
            continue;
        }            

         var p = o.value == '' ? undefined : usedValues[o.value];          
         if (p == undefined || p == s) {
             o.style.display = '';
         }          
         else {
             o.style.display = 'none';
         }
       }
    }
 }

HTML:
  <div>
      <select onChange="callSave(this)">
       <option></option>
       <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
       <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
      <option>F</option>
      <option>G</option>
      <option>H</option>
   </select>
  <select onChange="callSave(this)">
       <option></option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
      <option>F</option>
        <option>G</option>
       <option>H</option>
  </select>
   <select onChange="callSave(this)">
       <option></option>
       <option>A</option>
       <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
       <option>E</option>
       <option>F</option>
      <option>G</option>
      <option>H</option>
   </select>
   <select onChange="callSave(this)">
      <option></option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
      <option>F</option>
      <option>G</option>
      <option>H</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: code sample link: http://jsbin.com/enewey/edit#javascript,html,live  This code works fine in IE9 & chorme not in Older versions of IE.. Help me to work on IE7 & IE8..